# How to fetch the output in apache storm using nodejs

Tags: node.js, output, cpu-word, apache-storm

I am new to apache storm. The program is to split the incoming sentences into word and then doing a word count. I am facing a problem in console.log('in spout') and console.log(word) i.e. in fetching the output. I have attached the code below:

```
var storm = require('node-storm')

var randomsentence = (function() {
    var sentences = [
        "the cow jumped over the moon",
        "an apple a day keeps the doctor away",
        "four score and seven years ago",
        "snow white and the seven dwarfs",
        "i am at two with nature"
    ]
    console.log('before spout')
    return storm.spout(function(sync) {
        var self = this
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('in spout')
            var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*sentences.length)
            var sentence = sentences[i]
            self.emit([sentence]) /* {id:'unique'} //for reliable emit */
            sync()
        }, 100)
    }).declareOutputFields(["word"])
})()

var splitsentence = storm.basicbolt(function(data) {
    var words = data.tuple[0].split(" ")
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
        var word = words[i].trim()
        if (word) {
            this.emit([word])
            console.log(word)
        }
    }
}).declareOutputFields(["word"])

var wordcount = (function() {
    var counts = {}


    return storm.basicbolt(function(data) {
        var word = data.tuple[0]
        if (counts[word] == null) {
            counts[word] = 0
        }
        var count = ++counts[word]
        this.emit([word, count])
    }).declareOutputFields(["word", "count"])
})()



var builder = storm.topologybuilder()
builder.setSpout('randomsentence', randomsentence)
builder.setBolt('splitsentence', splitsentence, 8).shuffleGrouping('randomsentence')
builder.setBolt('wordcount', wordcount, 12).fieldsGrouping('splitsentence', ['word'])
//builder.setBolt('word',word,3).shuffleGrouping('wordcount')

var topology = builder.createTopology()

var options = {
    // name: 'optional... the default name is the name of the topology script',
    //nimbus: 'localhost:2181',
    //nimbus: '127.0.0.1:2181',
    nimbus: '172.26.4.227:2181',
    config: { 'topology.debug': true }
}
storm.submit(topology, options, function(err, topologyName) {
    // Handle error or submission success
if(err){console.log(err)}
console.log(topologyName)
})


//process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  //  console.log(err);
//});
```

Comment: Cool that you got something working I guess. I had trouble integrating a node.js bolt to our mixed-tech stack storm infrastructure using node-storm. I had better luck with storm-node module instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason that you're not seeing the output from `console.log('in spout')` and `console.log(word)` is because of the way storm distributes processing. The contents of the spout and bolt are going to be executed in worker processes on the various storm nodes in the cluster. It is on those storm nodes that the logs will be located.

Comment: To add to that, within the storm infrastructure, the console.log() might not work or work well. So generally, if you wanted to log/output something, best to call `storm.log(message)` or its equivalent in the storm library/module one is using. console.log() didn't work for me, storm logs spat out Java I/O exception from not liking that particular method.